# C++ including C file (typedef not found)

Tags: c++, c

I have this cpp file where I include bunch of C files.

**main.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
#include "types.h"
#include "file1.h"
}
...
```

**types.h**

```
#IFNDEF TYPES_H
#DEFINE TYPES_H
typedef unsigned short int char16;
...
#ENDIF // TYPES_H
```

**file1.h**

```
#include "file2.h"
...
```

**file2.h**

```
...
char16* testCode();
...
```

For some reason the compiler gives me an error that the char16 is not declared. Any idea why the include does not inheritate from the CPP file to the C-file? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `#IFNDEF`, `#DEFINE`, and `#ENDIF` are illegal preprocessing directives -- they *must* be lowercase.  Also you should not be wrapping the `#include` statements with `extern "C"`.  Put that *inside* the header files, protected by `#ifdef __cplusplus`/`#endif` pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the types.h in file2.h. You don't seem to be doing that.

Btw, the code posted compiles on my machine without any errors, whereas if I comment the `"#include "types.h"` in main.cpp, it gives me an error.

Comment: Ok true that. But there is a byrocracy problem with the file2.h and I cannot really do changes to it so is there any other way around the problem? And why is it not "inheritated" by the preprocessor?

Comment: I think I understand the problem, are you talking about when you include the same header file in multiple header files, the compiler complains about char16 being already defined? Maybe Jay knows if you can forward declare char16??

Comment: There is no problem including the types.h from many places as it is inside IFNDEF macro. The problem here is that I cannot do changes to file1.h or file2.h so I should get around the problem some other way. Though it might not be possible (?)

Comment: Can you post some more code or the exact error? It seems to be working on my machine.

Comment: "file2.h", line 25: Error:  #20: identifier "char16" is undefined is the exact error message